# How to set a border to an imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

[image]

I am working in an android application and I want to place an `ImageView` in a particular position in my view. For that I applied the particular code and worked successfully :

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mrng);
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(350);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

Now I want to set a border to this image. For that I made a an shape xml and I have set as the background of the image view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

But when I gave the background of the image view the shape it does not give the correct output.please help me.

I do not want a border around the ImageView, but rather border around the rotated image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** I'm completely rewriting my answer based on the clarification of the question.  Here's how I achieved what you want.  The idea is to draw the frame and then rotate:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.TestImage);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

    final int BORDER_WIDTH = 3;
    final int BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    Bitmap res = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap.getWidth() + 2 * BORDER_WIDTH,
                                     bMap.getHeight() + 2 * BORDER_WIDTH,
                                     bMap.getConfig());
    Canvas c = new Canvas(res);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(BORDER_COLOR);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, res.getWidth(), res.getHeight(), p);
    p = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    c.drawBitmap(bMap, BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH, p);

    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(350);
    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(res, 0, 0, res.getWidth(), res.getHeight(), mat, true);
    image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

And here's the screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: android:clipToBounds="true". I don't think there is a property like this in imageview

Comment: @Arun I know, got confused with iOS.  I updated my answer: it's `android:cropToPadding`

Comment: Hm... I just tested this - and it worked fine: I got a black border of 3dp around the image. I'm updating my answer with full XML that I used.

Comment: hi..Please put the code in the OnCreate method and test once again...Then you know the problem... ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.TestImage);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mrng);
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(350);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);

Comment: Please look into the screen shot that i have added. This is the output I got.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at your screenshot and I see the white background and black border - so what's the problem?

Comment: I want the border within the image. Now I an getting the while space since I have added matrix to my imageview. I want that black border within the image..Please help me

Comment: Ahh!.. So you want the black border around the rotated image, not around the imageview!  That's a completely different story!

Comment: Yea..that my requirement..How can we do this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12377/discussion-between-arun-and-aleks-g)

Comment: i'm using `paint.setAntiAlias(true);` but still border looks rough, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is way to put border around ImageView even any view in android. In XML put Four simple `<View>`'s on each side of the imageview. And these view's can be assigned any type of style. You can use relative layout in which you can place four borders easily around image view.

Kinda lengthy process but works.

Comment: This will work fine only with out the Matrix that I have applied. I have to work this fine with my matrix